# How to access fstab at reboot phase

Tags: linux, recovery

How can I access and modify /etc/fstab during reboot (maybe accessing to recovery mode) ?

Why this question :
I have updated the virtualbox guests additions in backtrack 5 (as a Virtualbox VM).
I have modified temporary the fstab file to do that but forgotten to turn it back to initial state, like :

```
mount /dev/cdrom /cdrom
echo "/dev/cdrom    /cdrom0 udf,iso9660 defaults,exec   0   0" >> /etc/fstab
```

So after the guest additions installed, reboot is blocked on mounting this unexisting point.

Thx

edit: maybe to move to serverfault ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possible solutions to your problem:

1. Use the recovery mode (if you don't see that in the grub list, edit the default entry and add the word "single" without quotes to the end of the kernel line)
2. Mount a random .iso file temporarily

Then remove the offending fstab line.

Comment: Thx I'll try that direction. The point is I have no grub and can't access the command line.

Comment: I tried Solution 2, eg I created a dummy.iso file chmoded 777 with just an shebang and an echo line. But I guess I can't do that with a bash script but with a compiled program, right ?

Comment: Thx. I accepted the answer as I think it's right but I did not succeed in doing that so I add to reimport a previous VM appliance.

Comment: Sorry I didn't check back on this question. GRUB is the bootloader, which your VM would use to start up your Linux kernel (unless you're using LILO, which would be pretty unusual). Depending on your distribution, you might need to hold down shift or tap escape during the boot sequence to reach the GRUB menu.

You'd actually need to use a valid ISO9660 file to resolve your problem via the second method, as a dummy would still be unmountable. Something like Damn Small Linux would have worked well.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I have no grub as the VM is a backtrack distro (based on Ubuntu but no grub access, eg I can't choose the linux kernel for example, or go for a recovery mode access). So yep, I'll try booting on a reliable linux iso like you suggested, or gparted as well. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to boot a Live OS and mount the root filesystem from there. Then you will be able to edit the fstab file.

Once you have the live OS booted
fdisk -l
-find your root partition (usually in the format sda1, sdc1, sda2, etc)
mkdir /mnt/rootfs
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/rootfs <--sda2 = root partition found in fdisk
cd /mnt/rootfs/etc
-Fstab file should be in there.

Comment: Thx. The point is that the current machine is a VM and I can't access it or transform it into a live CD or an ISO that I could mount and access from another OS.